# Why I get JS IntelliSense suggetions while editing html file

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

While editing html files I get `JS IntelliSense` even when I am writing css class names inside class attributes:

[image: editing html file]

[image: inside class attribute]

how can I customize the suggestion just to pop up js suggestion inside js file or script tag.

I am facing troubles writing emmet code and press tab or enter with this auto suggestion.

Thanx,

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl + , to open settings.json and then add inside of it

```
"html.validate.scripts": false
```

Which'll turn off javascript suggestions. If you also want to get rid of css suggestions in html you can also add the line

```
"html.validate.styles": false
```

Comment: didn't work, still getting the ???? js code suggestions....

Comment: You might have to exit outta it or something like that for it to refresh

Comment: also check that you saved it/make sure you put commas in the right place so it's proper json

Comment: I closed and reopened vs code after entering the settings and saved the setting but nothing worked

Comment: hmmm, weird. can I see what your settings.json looks like